# Google calendar sync & time zones

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, mobile-phone, google-calendar, time-zone

I use google sync to sync outlook 2003 and my google calendar and google's mail for exchange service to sync google calendar with my mobile phone.

If I travel to another time zone, my phone will automatically adjust to the new time zone, while I would prefer leaving my PC timezone unchanged. Will this cause a problem when I sync?

For example, if I enter an appointment as 11:00 NY time in outlook, it will display as 11:00 in google calendar and on my phone.  If I travel to London, it will remain 11:00 NY time in outlook, while my phone would show it as 15:00 (because the phone would adjust to local time and London is 4 hours ahead of NY at the moment).

Will this cause any problems?  What will google calendar show for this appointment when accessed from my PC (11:00?) or my phone (15:00?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 3 of those services (Outlook 2003, Google Calendar and your Phone) should support time zone based scheduling (that is, they record and display events as happening at 1pm EST as opposed to just 1pm).  This information should all transfer over when you're sync and show up properly.